# R: Glmer Model Error

Tags: r, model

By run of follow code in R:

```
m3 <- glmer(accoccur ~ Time + Year + Month  + holiday + HolidayNum  + (1 + Time | DistfKaraj) , data = accident, family = "binomial" , nAGQ =1)
```

Run stooped with this error:

```
Error in intI(i, n = x@Dim[1], dn[[1]], give.dn = FALSE) : 
  "anyNA" is not a BUILTIN function
```

Comment: What version of R are you running?

Answer (score 1):

`anyNA()` is a function that was introduced in R 3.1.0 -- search http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS for the function name. My guess is that you have the development version of `lme4` (hosted [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4)), which makes use of `anyNA()` (based on [the blame](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blame/2925a94bcc87776316e425b30ef057d0e239f32a/R/utilities.R), it was added in November 2014), but doesn't define it for you.

You have a few options:

1. Upgrade to at least R 3.1.0 -- current is 3.2.0.
2. Define `anyNA()` yourself, with `anyNA <- function(x) any(is.na(x))`

I'd recommend at least upgrading your version of R, unless you rely on packages that are unavailable in future versions.